# Is "undefined" in Javascript an error or just a notice?

Tags: javascript

Is the `undefined` message in the pop up or console log (e.g. when calling a variable that doesn't exist) an **ERROR** message or just a **NOTICE** message?

In PHP there is a difference, so, looking for your explanation on this subject.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: Strictly speaking about JavaScript only, there are no notices. You either have a syntax error or a runtime error. In both cases the code will terminate. If you get an alert displaying undefined, then it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it is a [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) (or a stringification of a value in the case of an alert)

Whether or not you can ignore the fact that a variable/property/whatever is `undefined` depends on the needs of the program you are writing. If a message displays "undefined" when it should display "sweet cuppin' cakes", then that would be a logic error; conversely, if a message displays undefined when it is merely intended to reflect an internal state that *can legitimately be undefined*, it would not be an error.

Comment: So, I can ignore the checks if it exists or not? If it's just a notice like in PHP I will ignore it. If it's an error I will have to doe checks. Or what do you suggest?

Comment: Whether or not you can ignore the fact that a variable/property/whatever is `undefined` depends on the needs of the program you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like an incomplete error message; like when a developer prints "This should never appear!11" Undefined is nothing more than a value, so seeing it on its own does not assign any meaning or importance to the message.

Answer (score 0):

'undefined' means exactly what it says - you have referenced a variable name that is not defined.

Some languages, like Python, are stricter about this kind of thing, and will throw an error if you try to do this.

Javascript assumes you know what you are doing, and so doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is a special data type. For example, a common case is a missing parameter in a function call:

```
var foobar = function(val)
{
    alert(typeof val); // alerts 'undefined'
    alert(foobar.length); // throws an error
}

foobar();
```

The author of this example function should have checked for the type of `val` before trying to access the `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined is, what its name says, a sign for something beeing not defined, like

```
var a=new Array(10);
```

It is an array: `Array.isArray(a)`is `true`, `a.length` is 10; but all it contains are `undefined` values: e.g. `a[5]` is `undefined`. So it is no error.

> ERROR message or just a NOTICE message?

Neither nor.